# Would iPad Air full screen ImageView fit as iPad Pro full screen ImageView

Tags: ios, ipad, uiimageview, screen-resolution

The largest Image I have is for iPad Air 2, 768x1024 pixels which fits full screen. Would this 768x1024 pixels image fit full screen on iPad Pro or would it look to small because of iPad Pro's new huge size?

I can't find out by myself, can't update to Xcode 7.1 from Mac App store, it always stops the download on its own I don't know why. I tried downloading from developer.apple.com/downloads and it keeps giving me an error. So I can't update to Xcode 7.1. So I can't find out.

Does iPad Air full screen images fit full screen in iPad Pro?

Comment: You already know the iPad Pro has much higher resolution. Why is this even a question?

Comment: So does it mean an image that fits full screen on iPad Air 2 won't fit full screen on iPad Pro?

Comment: Hint: A non-Pro iPad has a screen size (in points) of 1024x768. The Pro has a screen size (in points) of 1366x1024.